# TensorFlow 2.3.0 cannot define a complex64 type complex number

Tags: python, tensorflow

I run the following code in Google Colab (TensorFlow version: 2.3.0, Python version: 3.6.9) and got an error:

```
import tensorflow as tf
s = tf.constant(3*tf.math.exp(1j*4),dtype = tf.complex64)
print(s)
```

error:

```
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-6-23a80e1ab93a> in <module>()
      1 import tensorflow as tf
      2 
----> 3 s = tf.constant(3*tf.math.exp(1j*4),dtype = tf.complex64)
      4 print(s)

...
/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/constant_op.py in convert_to_eager_tensor(value, ctx, dtype)
     88     if dtype is not None and value.dtype != dtype:
     89       raise TypeError("Expected tensor with type %r not %r" % (
---> 90           dtype, value.dtype))
     91     return value
     92   if dtype is not None:

TypeError: Expected tensor with type tf.complex64 not tf.complex128
```

However it has no problem if I run (or just ignore the dtype):

```
import tensorflow as tf
s = tf.constant(3*tf.math.exp(1j*4),dtype = tf.complex128)
print(s)
```

results:

```
tf.Tensor((-1.960930862590836-2.2704074859237844j), shape=(), dtype=complex128)
```

So I guess complex128 is the default dtype for complex numbers in TF2.x and it doesn't support complex64?? Looks very weird to me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I gave it more try and found the reason:
If we run the following code, there is no problem:

```
import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np

a = 3*np.exp(1j*4)
print('data type of a:',a.dtype)
s = tf.constant(a,dtype = tf.complex64)
print(s)
```

results:

```
data type of a: complex128
tf.Tensor((-1.9609308-2.2704074j), shape=(), dtype=complex64)
```

Or we use the `tf.cast()` for tensor type conversion

```
import tensorflow as tf
tf.cast(tf.constant(3*tf.math.exp(1j*4)),dtype = tf.complex64)
```

results:

```
<tf.Tensor: shape=(), dtype=complex64, numpy=(-1.9609308-2.2704074j)>
```

So I think `dtype =`  cannot be used to convert one tensorflow dtype to another, instead we have to use tf.cast() to do the job. However, `dtype =`  can be used to convert the data type from a numpy array to a tensor.

Answer (score 0):

```
s = tf.constant(3*tf.math.exp(1j*4),dtype = tf.complex64)
```

Let's re-write this statement as,

```
>>> t = tf.math.exp(1j*4)
>>> t
<tf.Tensor: shape=(), dtype=complex128, numpy=(29.49950635904248+45.94275907707917j)>
>>> # This will default get created with type 'complex128'
>>> s = tf.constant(3*t, dtype=tf.complex64)    # Hence, this will raise error of getting complex128 if you specify 'complex64'
```

Instead you can create constant of `complex64` first and then give it to the one you want to create. This should resolve the issue.

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> tf.constant(3*tf.math.exp(np.complex64(1j*4)), dtype=tf.complex64)
```

Comment: Thanks @ranka47. The issue has been solved.